# jQuery + jQueryUi: .combobox() will ignore options with empty values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<option value="">Tutti</option>
<option value="3">Centro di deposito</option>
<option value="2">Distributore</option>
<option value="4">Fornitore</option>
<option value="1">Produttore</option>
<option value="5">Vettore</option>
```

If i use `.combobox()` to create a beautiful combobox, the empty value ('All' in english) is not showed.

How to workaround ?

Comment: Do you have any documentation about `combobox` method? I don't know it nor find it.

Comment: Well, the obvious workaround would be to give it a value like `0` or `-1` or `-` or something else that signifies "no value".

Comment: really sorry ... it was an internal function that mal-use jquery ui, really sorry ... i supposed it was a jqueryui native method, really sorry. . ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var options = $("option"), // Replace with the selector of this options.
    comboContainer = $("#container"); // Replace with the selector of the combo container.
$("<select></select>").append(options).appendTo(comboContainer);
```

Comment: As I said in my comment to your question, I don't know the `.combobox()` method. (Does it even exists?). But the code I posted creates a combo element with the options selected in `options` and puts it in the DOM as the last child of the `comboContainer`. What you should do is replace the selectors in my example with corresponding ones.